# get_query_var with add_rewrite_rule and add_filter('query_vars') not working

Tags: rewrite-rules

I've the following code to rewrite url and get the variable

```
add_rewrite_rule('galeria-de-honra/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=galeria-de-honra&galeria_year=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_filter('query_vars', 'galeria_de_honra_query_var');

function galeria_de_honra_query_var($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'galeria_year';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Where there already is a page with slug 'galeria-de-honra',

so, after this, in the front end i get the variable using the global $wp

```
global $wp;
$year = $wp->query_vars['galeria_year'];
if (!in_array($year, $years)) {
    $year = date('Y');
}
```

and it works fine, if you enter in the page without using the custom year it gets the atual year, and if you use url with year "/galeria-de-honra/2017", it gets year 2017, thats ok.

The point is, when i try to use get_query_var('galeria_year') it wont work

Using the url "/galeria-de-honra/2017" and the display code:

```
<?php 
$year = get_query_var('galeria_year');
echo "get_query_var('galeria_year'): $year";
$year = get_query_var('galeria_year', 5);
echo "<br>get_query_var('galeria_year', 5): $year";
global $wp;
$years = get_associados_anos_galerias_de_honra();
$year = $wp->query_vars['galeria_year'];
echo "\$wp->query_vars['galeria_year]': $year";
?>
```

i get the following output:

```
get_query_var('galeria_year'): 
get_query_var('galeria_year', 5): 5
$wp->query_vars['galeria_year]': 2017
```

How can i use the get_query_var('galeria_year') instead of going to the global $wp?

Comment: hm. have you check `parse_query` ? I mean, once you receiving this data, you can check what objects passed to wp_query in parse_query filter. its kinda useful for debug.

Comment: btw, you also can also do `$wp->get( 'galeria_year' )`, (`get_query_var` is wrapper around it.), but it supposes to work, if it doesn't  something gone wrong with wp_query. i would suggest to debug it on every stage (parsing wp_query for example...)

Comment: i havent done any debug or checks, it's the first time im doing something like this and i've not much knowledge about it. how could i debug it to check the stages?

Comment: Yes, i saw about $wp->get('galeria_year') but not even tested once i want to remove the use of global, but thanks for telling me that it works...

Comment: `get_query_var` fetches from global `$wp_query`, are you sure you don't overwrite this somewhere before trying to access the values?